# Get Geometry Position in shader before armature is applied?

Tags: armature, shaders

I'd like to use the Position output of the Geometry shader node as if an armature has not yet been applied.  In the image below I'm trying to extract the z position to input into the wave texture node to make a ribbed tube, but I want the ribs to follow the armature curve instead of staying z aligned.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out a minute after posting, the Generated output from the Texture Coordinate node works fine for this:

[image]